# program flow when ShowDialogue another window

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, program-flow

consider the flowing scenario

```
chequeInfo = new Check();
                Messenger.Default.Register<Check>(this, (a) => this.doSomething(a));
                AddNewCheck j = new AddNewCheck();
                _dialogService.showDialoge(j);
                Console.WriteLine("this text doesn't show up");
                SpecialCustomerPayments d = new SpecialCustomerPayments();                  
                d.chequeId = chequeInfo.Id;
                d.paymentAmount = chequeInfo.value;
                d.userId = 1;
                ....
```

as you can observe from code above I'm showDialog() another window in the middle of a method , I expected the flow to continue after I done with the new window , but it is not , I think I'm missing something obvious here, any help will be much appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowDialog()` is a blocking call.
It will only return when the new window is closed.

If you want it to return immediately and leave the window open, call `.Show()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply , do u mean after closing the new window , the rest of the method will execute ? that is what I actually expected and that is not happening , I checked using a Console.WriteLine("")

Comment: Then you're probably getting an exception.  Click Debug, Exceptions, and check all of the boxes.